# Сохранение blob видео-потока

Tags: html5, парсер, потоки-данных, blob

Есть страница с потоковым видео, которое нужно достать.

```
<video autoplay="" id="player4_nlplayerhtml5" 
     data-src="https://nlds328.cdnllnwnl.neulion.com/nlds_vod/nfl3/vod/2017/08/17/37187/e
    74a79/1_37187_bal_mia_2017_b_whole_1_pc.mp4.m3u8?h=123asd...." 
     crossorigin="use-credentials" src="blob:https://gamepass.nfl.com/a7156d0c-
    1acc-4e0c-90d7-df8d9c7e78fe">
</video>
```

По https://nlds328.cdnllnwnl.neulion.com/nlds_vod/nfl3/v.. 
Получаем список файлов разного рарешения. 
Берём одно из них и по https://nlds328.cdnllnwnl.neulion.com/nlds_vod/nfl3/v.. 
Получаем набор *.ts файлов и какой-то ключ.

**Вопрос: как всё это собрать в один файл?**

Comment: а на чем парсер то пишите?